# Adjust positioning and precision of quartile labels in ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following codes:

```
 quartiles5 <- datalong5 |> 
  group_by(Year, new, variable) |>
  reframe(y = quantile(value, c(.25, .5, .75), na.rm=TRUE))

 CAGR<-ggplot(datalong5, aes(x=Year, y=value, fill=new))+geom_boxplot( outlier.shape = NA, coef = 0)+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-0.1, 0.2))+scale_fill_discrete(name="")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())



CAGR+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, breaks = seq(-0.1, 0.3, by=0.05))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Forklaring") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.15))+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour = "black"))+
  geom_text(
    data = quartiles5,
    aes(
      x = Year,
      y = y,
      label = percent(y)),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

resulting in this boxplot:

[image: Picture of boxplot]

Any suggestion on how to make it look better? I would prefer the values to be displayed with two decimals and move the values of median and 3rd quartile a bit higher and move the 1st quartile a bit lower. However, open for all suggestions.

Comment: `label = percent(y, accuracy = 0.01)` should show 2 decimals in the labels. Easiest to use `vjust = 0` or other number to taste, or perhaps `vjust = "outward"` with that `geom_text` layer to adjust positioning.